# ubuntu 10.04 latest ati driver proble m

Tags: ubuntu

I got a problem with my Ubuntu 10.04 installation. I have downloaded and installed the latest driver frome Ati's website. The driver pckage has version 11.2. Now at start all I have is a blank screen with vertical green lines.

I tried the recovery mode with this code: `rm /etc/x11/xorg.conf` and a hope that it will reboot at default mode but, couldn't fin the package.

Is there a way to get back to the default driver that was working at first?

Answer (score 0):

If you use GRUB, you could type 'e' when choosing which OS to boot. (If not, there should be some other way to change boot options, e.g. F9).  Switch "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" to use older drivers in the boot options. You should be able to boot into your Ubuntu (albeit with low res) and make changes to your driver.